# It is possible to view what httprequest was sent by the browser when submitting a form?

Tags: debugging, firefox, browser, httprequest

When I submit a form on a site I want to know what HttpRequest was sent from the browser to the server, is this possible from any browser, or is there any firefox addon to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

IE9 has this functionality in the Developer Tools (press F12). In Firefox you can use the extension Firebug. For Opera you can use Dragonfly.

There is also an application that has much more functionality and allows you to change any values in the request: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/). Fiddler works with pretty much all browsers on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox there is the [Live HTTP Headers extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/).

For Internet Explorer, there is the [ieHTTPHeaders extension](http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders.html) which shows you HTTP requests and responses.